# allow wget & php deny from rest

Tags: .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent .*Wget* wget

Order deny,allow<br>
Deny from all<br>
Allow from env=wget

ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml
```

---

So I am currently using the above lines of text inside my `htaccess` file, and it works perfectly.  The problem is I need to allow access to a *mailer.php* file that is also listed in that directory.

Is there a way i can allow access to just this file and use the above code yet to block out the rest?

And if it matters, the phpfile writes to a file inside that directory... it is called *rc3.key* (not sure if that is important but i think it could be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following:

`<Files "mailer.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>`

This will allow everyone to access mailer.php but will throw a 403 error for every other file.